# NestJS- npm test is very slow with a beforeEach hook

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

I'm new to NestJS and i'm currently learning testing in NestJS.

Is it a common issue that having a `beforeEach` with a `createTestingModule().compile()` and some `module.get()` increase test execution so much ?

I have a dummy `expect(true)` test that takes 6 seconds to complete when having a `beforeEach` where it takes only 1 seconds without (and 1 second for this dummy test still seems a lot)...
This is very annoying when you are running test in watch mode since it takes a lot of time and still i have only on little test.

I couldn't find anything related to this issue with NestJS, so i'm probably something doing wrong but i couldn't figured what.

I did try to use some jest flags like `--runInBand` or `--maxWorkers=4` but without success.

--

*The tested application is really app created through a tutorial, nothing particular to notice on this side.*

Here is my `tasks.service.spec.ts` file (it's the only test file i have). I can provide a Github repo if it helps.

```js
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';

import { TaskRepository } from './task.repository';
import { TasksService } from './tasks.service';

const mockTaskRepository = () => ({});

describe('tasks.service', () => {
  let tasksService;
  let taskRepository;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        TasksService,
        { provide: TaskRepository, useFactory: mockTaskRepository },
      ],
    }).compile();

    tasksService = await module.get(TasksService);
    taskRepository = await module.get(TaskRepository);
  });
  describe('Test', () => {
    it('pass', () => {
      expect(true);
    });
  });
});
```

Here is my jest settings in `package.json`

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^src/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/$1"
    }
  }
```

Here is results with `beforeEach` commented and without `beforeEach` commented

```
# With beforeEach

PASS  src/tasks/tasks.service.spec.ts (7.214 s)
  tasks.service
    Test
      ✓ pass (10 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        7.241 s
Ran all test suites.

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.
```

```
# Without beforeEach

PASS  src/tasks/tasks.service.spec.ts
  tasks.service
    Test
      ✓ pass (2 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.561 s, estimated 8 s
Ran all test suites.

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.
```

Any tips or help are welcomed :-)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In a new project, adding in a timing command to check the overall time, I'm getting that the `beforeEach` hook takes about 2 to 10 milliseconds to run. The entire test suite took about 20 milliseconds and Jest reported the tests taking 3.20s overall, from start to stop. If anything, I'd say the problem is on Jest's side.

The tests in question, if you're curious:

```js
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { BarService } from './bar.service';

describe('BarService', () => {
  let service: BarService;

  beforeAll(() => {
    console.time(BarService.name);
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    console.timeEnd(BarService.name);
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    console.time('beforeEach')
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [BarService],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<BarService>(BarService);
    console.timeEnd('beforeEach');
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
  it('expect true', () => {
    expect(true);
  });
});
```

And the output from Jest:

```sh
$ jest bar.service
 PASS  src/bar/bar.service.spec.ts
  BarService
    ✓ should be defined (14 ms)
    ✓ expect true (3 ms)

  console.time
    beforeEach: 9 ms

      at Object.<anonymous> (bar/bar.service.spec.ts:22:13)

  console.time
    beforeEach: 2 ms

      at Object.<anonymous> (bar/bar.service.spec.ts:22:13)

  console.time
    BarService: 17 ms

      at Object.<anonymous> (bar/bar.service.spec.ts:12:13)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.554 s, estimated 3 s
Ran all test suites matching /bar.service/i.
Done in 3.20s.
```

Test were ran on the following architecture:

```
Linux/linux x64 5.4.0-42-generic ~Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-8130U CPU @ 2.20GHz (cores/threads): 4
```

Here's a [link to the git repo](https://github.com/jmcdo29/quick-test). I created a new project

```sh
nest new quick-test -p npm
```

Added the `console.time` and `console.timeEnd` and ran `npm run test`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your time! Do you have a github with your source so that i can compare your performance with mine?

Comment: I don't but I can set one up.

Comment: That would be nice of you 

Answer (score -1):

Try a `return` at the end of the `beforeEach` function.